# How to show that a set with injections into and from $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have two injective functions $u : \mathbb{N} \to A$ and $v : A \to \mathbb{N}$.

How can I demonstrate that $A$ is uncountable ?

If there is an injective function $u : \mathbb{N} \to A$ and $v : A \to \mathbb{N}$, consequently there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A$. But what can I do from that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "demonstrate that A is countable"?

Comment: That was my first thought... but the exercise wrote it that way... Perhaps that's a mistake... What's your thought?

Comment: Probably five or six other duplicates. I'm too lazy to find them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you've misread something or there's a typo in the exercise. If there is an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ then $A$ is **countable**; in fact, this is the definition of "countable"! *(Actually, your text might define countable as "in **bi**jection with $\mathbb{N}$;" the difference is whether we decide that finite sets are countable. Note that in this problem, the injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$ ensures that $A$ is infinite, so whichever definition you're using works.)*

Comment: Thanks Noah. My first reaction was indeed that one. My problem is why adding injection v:A→N. Don't you think there's something to do with it?

Comment: @Anna2801 I don't understand your comment. My answer says exactly that the existence of an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ (your "$\nu$") implies that $A$ is countable (or finite), that's the whole point.

Comment: Please check Cantor's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: @Anna2801 I am of course quite aware of Cantor's theorem. How do you think it is relevant here?

Comment: That's why I am doubting... Maybe it's a tricky question  :'(

Comment: @Anna2801 It's not a tricky question, it's a **incorrect** question. That's the whole point of my answer - the thing the question is asking you to show is **false**!

Comment: Thanks Noah. Probably the part " v:A→N" is an injection, is unrelevant here, even if the question was "Show that A is countable"

Comment: @Anna2801 No, it's **absolutely** relevant; the existence of an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ shows that $A$ is countable (or finite)! If your definition allows finite sets to be countable, then the $\mu$ part is completely irrelevant; otherwise, the $\mu$ part is needed to show that $A$ is countable as opposed to finite.

Comment: Sorry Noah, I am confused. I wanted to say  u:N→A irrelevant. That helps to deduce we have a bijection between N and A.  But we could just use " v:A→N" is an injection" to affirm we have a countable set? (thanks again for the patience...)

Comment: @Anna2801 Yup! Unless your text defines "countable" as "in **bi**jection with $\mathbb{N}$," that is unless your text doesn't consider finite sets to be countable. In that case $\mu$ is used to rule out the possibility that $A$ is finite.

Comment: You're a genius... actually my class text defines countable as in bijection with N". Which is unfortunate because I was reading all around that the injection between A to N was enough. Thanks! Anna